# Is there anything like attached data storage for a view?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I'm having hard time using Views with [i18n Views](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews). What gets me very irritated is that the translations of global fields (headers, footers, etc.) get lost whenever I make changes to that View. I would feel more comfortable if I could somehow permanently attach to a view some custom data, variables, i18n string arrays, and use them both in Views UI and tpl files.

I would imagine to declare a variable named `%my_footer` and provide its translations in a module. Then, in a footer I imagine being able to enter something like `<h3>This is %my_footer</h3>` or call in a tpl file by saying something like ` and have it rendered in the current translation.

The only thing I would hate to compromise on (as instructed by many users here) is to use PHP code in Views UI text fields.

So, is my scenario possible? I just love to have a single data source...

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable in code, you can do that with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [ctools contexts](http://www.gizra.com/content/ctools-context-tutorial).